# How to stop QSettings altering the order of key=value pairs in setting file?

Tags: qt5, ini, qsettings

In my program I have a Microsoft's INI style settings/configuration file that is created, edited and stored using the convenient `QSettings` class but the user may manually edit this file using the program itself, or any text editor she desires like `gedit` or `vim`. The order in which key=value pairs appear is important. The problem is whenever I try to store the changes at shutdown time, the order of key=value pairs change to a random order and it seems impossible to stop `QSettings` from changing it. For clarification here's a sample of a configuration file:

```
[AlarmGroup1]
DateTimeNotInitialized=1
DateTimeStampError=2
ParametersMissingOrInconsistent=3
NotInitialized=4
FlashMemoryFatalError=5
NotIdentified=6
```

which changes to:

```
[AlarmGroup1]
ParametersMissingOrInconsistent=3
DateTimeNotInitialized=1
DateTimeStampError=2
NotInitialized=4
FlashMemoryFatalError=5
NotIdentified=6
```

Is it possible to avoid the change of order? Why is `Qsettings` behaving like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QSettings behaves like this because the problem it was designed to solve was saving/retrieving single key/value pairs, not ordered lists of pairs.

To solve this you will need to either :

- Remove the requirement for a specific order from you program
- Write your own equivalent of QSettings
- Write a "custom storage format provider" to pass into QSettings http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#registerFormat

Comment: Have you tested the last option?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I went for the first option.

Comment: I used a `SQLite` database instead. The order stays the same in the table and it has really good performance and security. Using the third option you mentioned, I guess we can have a read and a write function that perform on a `SQLite` database file. I'm no longer working on this but your answer sounds plausible so I'll accept it.